# Как обойти изменение данных во время работы ThreadPool?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть пул, `scheduledAtFixedRate`, он считает налоги раз в `N` времени и в `run()` происходит обработка.

Проблема в том, что когда налог меняется во время действия таска, то в `run()` он выдаёт уже новое значение (которое менялось), а должен довести тик и выдать старое, а потом в новый тик уже положить новое. Как осуществить такую разводку?

Comment: В начале работы метода сохранять в локальную переменную текущее значение и использовать ее в пределах метода?

Comment: или используйте ReentrantLock, чтобы налог не менялся во время действия таска, а подождал.

Comment: Спасибоу! Использовал вариант через переменную. Про ReentrantLock уже пошёл читать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не синхронизированый доступ к переменным во время выполнения метода.

1) Синхронизировать и блокировать доступ к объекту через конструкцию `syncronized(executedObject){ }`

2) использовать `ReentrantLock` когда метод начинает выполняться.

Comment: Я бы добавил, что нужно использовать одно из двух, т.к. ReentrantLock это универсальная альтернатива syncronized, как и весь пакет java.util.concurrent может заменить старенькие wait(),notify(),notifyAll().

Answer (score 0):

В начале работы метода сохранять в локальную переменную текущее значение и использовать ее в пределах метода.